# Create Objects inside an Object at Runtime(Dynamically) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am actually just building a form with vanilla JavaScript and I need a little help regarding how can we create something like this at runtime,

```
const users = {
   user1 : { name : "xyz", password : "1234", email : "xyz@gmail.com" },
   user2 : { name : "abc", password : "1111", email : "abc@gmail.com" }
};
```

I want this because am using local storage to set values at run time but it only sets user1 values and not multiple users so please need a code which would help. Also it would be helpful to check whether below code is valid or not:

```
function submitData(inputArray) {
    inputArray.forEach(input => {
        users.push(input.value);
        localStorage.setItem(`${input.id}`, JSON.stringify(users))
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to create array of users and not an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.push` only works off of arrays.
If you had an array of objects you can make this work a little bit better, but you would lost the ability to look up a user, rather than having to iterate through the array to find it.

What you could do if you **really** wanted to go through this route is find the last users number and create that as the property for the next object.

something like this.

```js
const newUserNumber = Object.keys(users).length + 1
const user = 'user' + newUserNumber
users[user] = input.value
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function submitData(inputArray) {
    inputArray.forEach(input => {
        const userKey = 'user' + (Object.keys(users).length + 1);
        users[userKey] = input.value
        localStorage.setItem(`${input.id}`, JSON.stringify(users))
    });
}
```

Comment: Definitely I know that I added it that but can You tell me how can I add something like , `const users = { user1 : { name=" ", password=" " }, user2 : {name= " ", password=" "} };`